# ipaddress.IPv4Network iterate through 1 host part

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to generate a list of IP address within a certain IPv4Network.

But instead of return a list like `10.0.0.1, 10.0.0.2, 10.0.0.3`. The code below works on this.

I would like to see a list like `10.0.1.0, 10.0.2.0, 10.0.3.0`. How do I get the code below to do this?

```
ip_range = [str(ip) for ip in ipaddress.IPv4Network('10.0.0.0/24')]
```

Comment: `10.0.1.0` isn't in `10.0.0.0/24`. Are you looking for a `255.255.0.255` netmask (i.e. `10.0.x.0`) or a `/16` (i.e. `10.0.x.y`)? Because the former isn't a valid netmask and will require postprocessing of a `/16`.

Comment: Could you show me a sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script will generate addresses 10.0.1.0, 10.0.2.0, 10.0.3.0, ...

```
import ipaddress
from itertools import islice

def generate_addresses():
    for ip in islice(ipaddress.IPv4Network('10.0.0.0/16'), 0, None, 256):
        yield '.'.join(str(ip).split('.')[:-1] + ['0'])

print('\n'.join(generate_addresses()))
```

Prints:

```
10.0.0.0
10.0.1.0
10.0.2.0
10.0.3.0
10.0.4.0
10.0.5.0
10.0.6.0
...and so on.
```

EDIT: To store it into the list, you could use this:

```
ip_range = [*generate_addresses()]
```